# My search results leave off 1 record ever time

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am using the below results with pagination and sorting code on several pages on my site. It works fine, except that in every case, it leaves off 1 record REGARDLESS what the sql query is. The results display works correctly. If there are 20 results, it will say showing 20 of 20 results. However, there will only be 19 results displayed on the page. What could be causing one record not show?

```
// Find out how many items are in the table
$total = $dbh->query("select
count(*)
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON posts.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE posts.active=1")->fetchColumn();

// How many items to list per page
$limit = 8;

// How many pages will there be
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);

// What page are we currently on?
$page = get_query_var('page', 1);
$page = is_numeric($page) && $page > 0 ? $page : 1;


// Calculate the offset for the query
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

$sort_columns = array('id' => 'posts.SID', 'name' =>
'posts.story_name', 'category' =>
'posts.category'); 
$sort_column = isset($_GET['sort']) & array_key_exists($_GET['sort'],  
$sort_columns) ? $sort_columns[$_GET['sort']] : 'stories.SID';

$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) & array_key_exists($_GET['sort'],  
$sort_columns) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'id';

$direction = isset($_GET['direction']) && in_array($_GET['direction'],
 array('asc', 'desc')) ? $_GET['direction'] : 'desc';

// The "back" link
 $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?
 page=1&sort='.$sort.'&direct='.$direction.'" title="First page">&laquo;
 </a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) .
 '&sort='.$sort.'&direct='.$direction.'" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;
 </a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span
 class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

// The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) .   
'&sort='.$sort.'&direct='.$direction.'" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> 
<a href="?page=' . $pages . '&sort='.$sort.'&direct='.$direction.'"
title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span>
<span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

// Display the paging information


$results = $dbh->prepare("select
wp_users.ID AS user_id,
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
posts.SID,
posts.post_name,
posts.category,
posts.created
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON posts.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE posts.active = 1
ORDER BY {$sort_column} {$direction} LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");

$results->execute();

$rows = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<?php if(sizeof($rows) > 0) : ?>
<style>
    .table {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="?sort=id<?php if($sort == 'id' && $direction ==
 'desc') echo '&direction=asc'; ?>">ID</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=name<?php if($sort == 'name' && $direction == 
'desc') echo '&direction=asc'; ?>">Post Name</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=category<?php if($sort == 'category' &&  
 $direction == 'desc') echo '&direction=asc'; ?>">Category</a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['SID']; ?></td>
             <td><a href="http://example.com/posts?posted
=<?php echo $row[SID]; ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($row['post_name']); ?>
</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>

<?
// Display the paging information
echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, '  
pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ', 
$nextlink, ' </p></div>';
```

Comment: it will be a limit issue, look at the maths to caculate it

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just can't figure out what is off on the math. I have tried +1 and a few other things, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Try changing `$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;` to `$offset = ($page) * $limit;`. If that doesn't work, try `$start = $offset + 1;` to `$start = $offset;`.

Comment: Well, the first option didn't work, but when I changed $start = $offset; (without the +1) it does give me all the results. However, when I do that, the display information says showing "results 0-10" instead showing "results 1-10". I guess I could live with that, but obviously I would prefer to have it show all the results and have the page info display correctly.

Comment: I came up with this work  around. Changed $start = $offset as you suggested to get the correct results. But then I also added $start++ right before the display code so that it says "displaying 1-20 of 200" results instead of displaying "0-20 of 200 results"